# Empty List View (list fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-listfragment

When app is running i see empty layout "no data". What can i do?
Trying AsyncTask, but doesent work. I dont know what to do. Im android newbie. 
May be i used wrong way? And trying to inflate view is not good idea?

```
public class MyEmployeFragment extends ListFragment {


    MyTask task;
    static String employer_id;
    static String employer_name;
    static String employer_last_name;
    String str = null;
    ArrayList<spr_item> ret_data = null;
    // имена атрибутов для Map
    final String ATTRIBUTE_ID   = "p_id";
    final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "p_name";
    final String ATTRIBUTE_LAST_NAME = "p_last_name";
    View v;
    ListView listView;
    SimpleAdapter sAdapter;

    ListView lvSimple;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        task    = new MyTask();
        task.execute();

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                                     Bundle savedInstanceState)  {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_employe, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Updating the action bar title
        getActivity().getActionBar();

        // массивы данных
        // String[] userId      = {employer_id};
        // String[] userName    = {employer_name};
        // String[] userLatName = {employer_last_name};

        ret_data = new  ArrayList<spr_item>();
        //ret_data.add(new spr_item("11","22","33"));
        //ret_data.add(new spr_item("111","222","333"));
        //ret_data.add(new spr_item("1111","2222","3333"));

        // упаковываем данные в понятную для адаптера структуру
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                ret_data.size());
        Map<String, Object> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < ret_data.size(); i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_ID, ret_data.get(i).getId() );
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,ret_data.get(i).getName() );
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_LAST_NAME,ret_data.get(i).getLastName() );
            data.add(m);
        }

        // массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
        String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME,ATTRIBUTE_LAST_NAME};
        // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
        int[] to = { R.id.tw_employe_id ,R.id.tw_employe_name, R.id.tw_employe_last_name};

        // создаем адаптер
        SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.list_item_employee,
                from, to);

        // определяем список и присваиваем ему адаптер
        lvSimple = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);

        return v;

    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                String s = "5ACACEC6-752B-4EFF-AA50-EEBE58A52113";
                // String user_guid = myPrefs.getString("guid", "");

                HttpActivity _http = new HttpActivity("192.168.10.11", "80");
                _http.set_addr_protocol("/WebSite/P/spr/spr.aspx/");
                _http.add_param("query", "spr_employee_get");
                // _http.add_param("p_guid", user_guid.toString().trim());
                _http.add_param("p_guid", s);
                _http.send();

                ret_data = _http.getArrayParamValue();

                //employer_name = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_name");
                //employer_id = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_id");
                //employer_last_name = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_last_name");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you instantiate your adapter your data is empty. You should either set adapter in onPostExecute method of AsyncTask, or call `sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` so adapter will update views with data obtained

Comment: Setting adapter onPostExecute does not effect.Try  to         sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Are you creating a new adapter in onPostExecute? That should have effect. Moreover, I would suggest you to avoid using SimpleAdapter and write your own Adapter subclassing ArrayAdapter, in this case it'll be much easier for you to modify your ListView contents

Comment: why you are taking seperate listview..! instead directly write setListAdapter.

Comment: @GVSharma actually it is not a separate ListView it's the same but addressed in another way in both ListActivity and ListFragment a ListView has id=android.R.id.list

Comment: OK, I see where the problem is, SimpleAdapter requires data to be prepared in a special way, there is a piece of code which does that. So this piece of code should be executed after you load data not before. After that you can create adapter and set it to your ListView.

Comment: As for NullPointerException, I assume that you've removed that part which initializes sAdapter and it's null